# Creating a layout that looks same on all screen sizes and densities

Tags: android, user-interface

How to create just one `layout` that looks the same on all screen `sizes` and `densities`?

Also, using a single `high resolution` `drawable` instead of `different resolution` `drawables` for `different screens` a **bad practice**?

Comment: use linear layout and weight to fix equally for all devices and in case of drawble put hdpi,mdpi ,ldpi all sizes image in drawble

Comment: "How to create just one layout that looks the same on all screen sizes and densities?" -- that is impossible to answer in the abstract. How you would design a first-person shooter game's UI for "all screen sizes and densities" is very different from how you would design a banking app's UI for "all screen sizes and densities", and so on. [The documentation has some general guidance](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html). Beyond that, you would need to get **much** more specific about your concerns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use linear layout with weight. it will support all devices in any orientation.

Using a high resolution drawable for all devices is a bad practice. High resolution drawable can make ur app slower on low-resolution devices.